# The meaning of v-ta+であろう

Tags: grammar

What does v-た+であろう mean?  For example:

> ほんの一、ニ分のやりとりで**あったであろう**が、いかに屈託のない若い人たちの闊達さがさわやかであった。

Does it mean something is likely to be that way? But what then if it appears that this thing has already happened?

Comment: Yeah, im afraid you are right. It could also describe the current condition.

Comment: Thank you for adding some context!  If you can make sure to supply context with future questions as well, it'll help people to write specific, helpful answers.

Answer (score 6):

It should be clear from a direct translation of the whole sentence:

> ほんの一、ニ分のやりとりであったであろうが、いかに屈託のない若い人たちの闊達さがさわやかであった。
>   The exchange was probably *no more than** one or two minutes but the generosity of *those*** carefree young people was so refreshing.

*Notes*
*ほんの really means "just" but "no more than" feels more natural so I've taken a little literary license.

** We don't really have a word like その to represent "those" and you have not given any more context so I've added it to make the sentence more complete as a stand alone statement.

であった is past/perfect copula similar to だった or でした equivalent to "was"

であろう is similar to だろう & でしょう and equivalent to "probably".

*Comment*:  The grammar is fairly straight forward but this sentence contains some quite difficult words. Did you read and understand the rest of the sentence before asking the question?

Comment: This sentence is a bit difficult for me as a novice language learner( I only started it three months ago).  Especially the first half sentence,  none of the grammers you just mentioned seems familiar to me.

Comment: @ingermafan: If you don't mind me saying so, it sounds like you are trying to run before you can walk.

Comment: Sadly , its grabbed from my homework, and I was supposed to prepare the reading material before class. No doubt new grammers would be taught on class latter, but I feel this way of learning is more active. Maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

By adding 「であろう」, the narrator turned the statement before it, i.e. 「ほんの一、二分のやりとりであった」, into a supposition, which sounds softer:

> (I think / feel / Probably) the exchange lasted for just one minute or two(, well, it might in fact be longer than that). (Although the duration was short,<strike>it is  enough to show</strike>) <strike>clearly</strike> [1]...

[1]: Sorry that I confused 「さわやか」 with 「あざやか」, credit to Tim

Comment: BTW, I feel unsure about the 「いかに」 here. 「いかにも屈託のない若い人たち」 and 「いかに...さわやかだったであろう」　sound fine to me. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: 「いかにも」のほうが自然ですよね。

Comment: @Choko Many thanks for the suggestion. It seems to me that 「いかにも」 can both couple with 「屈託のない」 and 「さわやかであった」 so that the sentence standalone sounds kind of ambiguous. Is that true?

Comment: I think the いかにも modifies 屈託のない. If it modified さわやか, you'd place it right before さわやか: → 「～～がいかにもさわやかであった」

Comment: Does 「いかにも]means [でも]?

Comment: @Choko: So I should put the "so" in my translation before the carefree not the refreshing? I did wonder but in English it seems so(!) much more natural if it modifies "refreshing"

Comment: http://wap.liba.com/t_99_1365347_128.htm　ここに原文があったけど、「どうそ」「つからたから」など、たまにタイポが・・・。これ以外に、載っているところないですかね。。見つかりません・・・

Comment: @Tim If the いかに is a typo for いかにも, then I think it modifies 屈託のない. If it really is いかに, then I have no idea...

Comment: あった　http://www.hankcs.com/nihongonote/xinbianriyuyueduwenxuan-diyice-02.html やっぱり「いかに」ですね。でも、中国語があるから意味はわかるかも？

Comment: In the Chinese translation, only the expression corresponding to 屈託のない, i.e. "毫无顾虑", got an intensifier embedded. It seems that the translator coupled いかに with 屈託のない, although 1. when it comes to tricky details, I do not have much faith in translation (BTW, 一、ニ分 in the same sentence was translated into "两三分钟", i.e. two or three minutes); 2. いかに still sounds kind of weird to me.

Comment: @Choko The いかに is actually the primary thing that made me conclude that it was であろうが in the sense of であれ; 「いかに」 is very often used with those, and is not a typo.

Comment: Is いかに without a following も or か older-style Japanese?  (Here meaning なんと?)

Comment: @rintaun If that were the case, 「いかに」 should have preceded 「であろうが」, [e.g.](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AB%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82)

Comment: @snailboat Yes I thought of that too, and checked a 古語辞典 but I'm still not sure... Yes I think いかに≒なんと and いかにも≒なんとも

Comment: @Noir そのサイトの文章は、日本語→中国語訳だと思いますか、それとも中国語→日本語訳でしょうか？

Comment: @Choko 上海外国教育出版社が出版した日本語学習材料にあったもので、日本語→中国語訳だと思います。もともとの出所は[この本](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E8%A3%8F%E7%AA%93%E3%81%AE%E9%A2%A8%E6%99%AF-%E5%A4%96%E5%B1%B1-%E6%BB%8B%E6%AF%94%E5%8F%A4/dp/4885462142)のようです。

Comment: @Noir That's a good point. Looking through BCCWJ, it does seem that いかに is always followed by ～か or ～Vよう.