# Meaning of verb + であろう

Tags: volitional-form

I'm watching *Koukyoushihen Eureka Seven*, and I'm noticing several uses if the titular form, like this one:

> クダンの限界を超えた時に選択をする**であろう**スカブコーラルの考えまでもな‌

Since I can't find anything specific about this form I'm guessing is the usual "probably", like in [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17672/the-meaning-of-v-ta%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86) answer, but the subtitles translate it without any kind of dubitative:

> Even to how the scub‌ corals will think and decide when we surpass the Question Limitation

So I was wondering if this form has any particular meaning, of it can just be translated as a form of weakening/dubitative, so the example should mean something on the line of "Also the thought of the Scub Corals, that could/will **probably** decide when the kudan limit is surpassed".

Comment: Are the "scub corals" something that has its own thoughts?

Comment: @aguijonazo yes, they are sentient.

Comment: Your understanding of であろう seems correct, but I think it’s the “scub corals” that will choose a particular way of thinking, as (kind of) suggested by the translation in the subtitles.

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding too, my doubt if they **will** decide (i.e., it's sure), as per subtitle; or if they will **probably** decide, since there is であろう. Also, is my "the thought of the Scrub Corals" translation right? I'm wondering since you translated "will choose a particular way of thinking".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This であろう is indeed what you think it is. It does express a supposition. In this particular context, however, it seems this supposition is not of the speaker but of someone called アドロック as the line before that says:

> アドロックは、そこまで読んでいたというわけだ

It is hard to tell who does 選択 without fully knowing the context. If it’s スカブコーラル, the sentence would be literally translated as something like:

> [Adroc read (= understood or anticipated)] even (up to) the thought of the Scub Corals that [they (= the Scub Corals)] would likely choose when [we] surpassed the Limit of Questions.

The translation in the subtitles seems OK.

Comment: "When we surpassed" is the moment when they will decide, not the thing they will decide, right? I first understood that way, since 超えた時に sounds to me like that's when the decision is taken (while for "that's what is being decided" I'd expect を), but reading your reply I'm not sure my understanding is right.

Comment: @Mauro - Not sure why my answer made you doubt your understanding. The object of 選択する is （〜の）考え (if my guess is correct). The English sentence is a very literal translation. It's not meant to be idiomatic.

Comment: As far as I understand, the English sentence "the Scub Corals would likely choose when we surpassed the Limit of Questions" could be read two ways: "the Scub Corals would likely choose [something in the moment in which] we surpassed the Limit of Questions" and "the Scub Corals would likely choose when we surpassed the Limit of Questions", i.e. "when we surpassed" can be the moment when the choice is done, or the thing which is chosen; I read it to be the first, but then I had some doubt (the same doubt with the subtitles, I just didn't notice it then).